# GStreamer opusdec: Try decode Opus bitstream failed

Tags: gstreamer, ogg, opus

## Initial Issue

I would like to use gstreamer plugin **opusdec** to decode an **Opus bitstream**. The final purpose is to make glue around it with appsrc and appsink as input/output, to  decode 20 ms Opus packets coming from a RTP packet payload and provide PCM sample.

*Remark: I can't use gstreamer rtpopusdepay*

The following pipeline works:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testvector01.bit.opus ! oggdemux !
>   opusdec ! fakesink

In my final application I'm no expected OGG contained data so I did the following:

1) Desencapsulate Opus bitstream

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testvector01.bit.opus ! oggdemux !
>   filesink location = testvector01.bit.demux

That works. And then:

2) Decode Opus bitstream

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testvector01.bit.demux ! opusdec !
>   fakesink

and I have the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason error (-5)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ..
```

**Input File**

*testvector01.bit.opus* 
From Opus test vector :https://people.xiph.org/~greg/opus_testvectors/

**My question is:**
*What is the proper way to use gstreamer plugin opusec without transport container?*

## Update

**Gstreamer  version 1.2.4**

As recommended I tried to add opusparse after filesrc and got the following error.

```
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

(gst-launch-1.0:5147): GStreamer-WARNING **:
gstpad.c:4555:store_sticky_event:<opusparse0:src> Sticky event
misordering, got 'caps' before 'stream-start'

(gst-launch-1.0:5147): GStreamer-WARNING **:
gstpad.c:4555:store_sticky_event:<opusdec0:sink> Sticky event
misordering, got 'caps' before 'stream-start' Pipeline is PREROLLED
... Setting pipeline to PLAYING ... New clock: GstAudioSinkClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOpusDec:opusdec0:
Decoding error: -4 Additional debug info: gstopusdec.c(460):
opus_dec_chain_parse_data ():
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOpusDec:opusdec0 Execution ended after
0:00:00.063372478 Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Setting pipeline to
READY ... Setting pipeline to NULL ... Freeing pipeline ...
```

**GStreamer 1.8.1**

The following pipeline

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = testvector01.bit.demux ! opusparse !
>   opusdec ! audioconvert ! alsasink

halt here:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ... Pipeline is PREROLLING ...

**Gstreamer 1.13.1**

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = testvector01.bit.demux ! opusparse !
>   opusdec ! alsasink

Playback just produce a short audio glitch while no gstreamer error is raised.

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location = testvector01.bit.opus ! oggdemux ! opusparse !
>   opusdec ! alsasink

Playback is choppy while no gstreamer error is raised.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
appsrc is-live=true do-timestamp=true name=audiosrc ! opusparse ! oggmux ! filesink location=test.ogg
```

gstreamer 1.14.1  works fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parser (opusparse) in between as opusdec doesn’t know what format it is, try the following pipeline:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=testvector01.bit.demux ! opusparse !
>   opusdec ! fakesink dump=true

Comment: I did try it on demuxed ogg file and it worked perfectly, Can you attach your file ? Also what version of gstreamer are you using (tested on 1.8.3)? seems like you need to update gstreamer!

Comment: As mentionned above I tested with 1.2.4 and 1.8.1. Both failed (a different wya). It seems that opusparse is buggy at least on  1.2.4. Find reference to this thread: http://gstreamer-bugs.narkive.com/4bOQI7bM/bug-741321-new-problem-using-opusparse-between-decoder-and-encoder

Comment: Tested testvector01.bit.opus on ubuntu 16.0.4 running gstreamer version 1.8.3, works perfect!

Comment: Unfortunatly, you are right  Prabhakar Lad. Upgraded to 1.13.1 and it works.

Comment: I also tried to upgrade libopus, opusparse and oped  individually with no success. If some one have a clue,  it will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you mean ? once comment says "Upgraded to 1.13.1 and it works" and later " libopus, opusparse and oped individually with no success." If you are just upgrading the library libopus and not gstreamer it wont help!

Comment: The fact is I'd better not change my gstreamer version. So I'm try to understand what shll be updated individualy to path my gstreamer version with only the change need.

Comment: See update above. With 1.13.1 there is no more gstreamer erro raised but th play back fails